# Vue mouseover not causing changes to the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I am trying to attach a `v-mouseover` directive to a bootstrap Vue element `b-list-group-item` as shown below.

```
<b-row>
    <b-col cols="3">
    <b-list-group> 
        <b-list-group-item :active="register"
        @click="switchRegister" button 
        @mouseover="isRegisterHover = true"
        @mouseleave="isRegisterHover = false"
        class="border-0 bg-transparent register"> Register </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
    </b-col>

    <b-col cols="9">
       <div id="action-screen-canvas-register v-if="isRegisterHover"> </div>
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

The variable `isRegisterHover` is tied to the boolean value in the data which determines whether or not the div will be shown.

```
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Navi
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isRegisterHover: false,
      // ...
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Thing is that the `action-canvas-register` div remains hidden when I hover the item, Vue devtool also shows that the data remains unchanged when I mouseover them. How do I make the `isRegisterHover` value change when I mouse-over the item?

Comment: I think this is more a copy paste and not the actual error, but you forgot the second `"` in your `id` name. Otherwise it should work

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo made before copy-pasting the code to SO. The actual code has a second `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with pure CSS if you wanted to. You could do something like:

```
<template>
    <div id="target">Hover this</div>
    <div>...</div>           // This will be hidden when #target is hovered
</template>

<script>
    ...
</script>

<style>
    #target:hover + div {
        visibility: hidden;  // Hides the element like v-show
        or
        display: none;       // Hides the element like v-if
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. [See this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

I would recommend using v-show instead of v-if. [See this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show).

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isRegisterHover: false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div @mouseover="isRegisterHover = true"
       @mouseleave="isRegisterHover = false">Hover this</div>
  <div v-show="isRegisterHover">This will show/hide (v-show)</div>
  <div v-if="isRegisterHover">This will show/hide (v-if)</div>
</template>
```